# How to organize multithreading

Tags: python, django, pyqt5

I have code, comes up WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread, but the code runs, but 1 time, when it starts to run 2 times the site dies, how can I arrange multi-threading that it would not crash?

```
from .forms import UserForm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django import forms
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
import sys
import time
import re
import requests

regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)"

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self,url):
        global app
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print("Load Finished")

    def Callable(self,data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

def index(request):
    submitbutton= request.POST.get("submit")
    
    From=''
    To=''
    url=''
    prices = []
    
    form= UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        From = (form.cleaned_data.get("From")).partition(", ")[2]
        To = (form.cleaned_data.get("To")).partition(", ")[2]


        regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)|price_85d2b9c\D+(?P<pric>\d+\s+\d+)"
        url = "https://www.aviasales.ru/search/"+From+"1012"+To+"23121?request_source=search_form&expected_price_currency=rub&expected_price_source=calendar"
        print(url)
        client_response = Client(url)
        #print(client_response.html)

        test_str = client_response.html
        
        matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
            print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

            for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
                groupNum = groupNum + 1
                print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
                prices.append("{group}".format(group = match.group(groupNum)))                                                              

        
    context= ({'form': form, 'From': From,
              'To': To, 'submitbutton': submitbutton,'prices': prices})

    return render(request, "index3.html", context)
```

I tried using the QThreadPool Class, but it didn't work correctly. What can I do to make the code handle links and not crash.

Comment: You don't even use `Client` in this code..?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code, already corrected

Comment: Right. Since you're presumably running under the Django dev server, it may run your code on variable threads. If you really do need QWebEnginePage (instead of just a request), I would recommend running it in a subprocess using e.g. `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Unless the content of the page is completely dynamical, I would just use a simple request. If it is dynamical, then consider using selenium. If for any (*valid* and thoughtfully considered) reason QWebEnginePage is a requirement, then you cannot do it like that, as only a QApplication instance should ever exist (recreating one is difficult and often cause of issues like this). Also, running an event loop in the `__init__` is *not* a good idea. Keep a running QApplication until it's needed, and use a QEventLoop instead of the QApplication one.